# Can't print an object from a class

Tags: python, class, object, printing

sorry but I just started learning python not too long ago and I'm stuck in thisprogram code, I just can't get it to work like it should.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name,breed,owner):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.owner = owner

class Person():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name


mick = Person("Mick Jagger")
dog = Dog("Stanley","French Bulldog",mick)
print(dog.owner)
```

I want to get the dog's owner name but all I get is this:

```
= RESTART: C:/Coding Practice/Object Oriented Programming.py =
<__main__.Person object at 0x000002C5DFB02050>
```

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__str__` or `__repr__` to get all the object's attributes in a more human-readable format.

`__str__` (read as "dunder (double-underscore) string") and `__repr__` (read as "dunder-repper" (for "representation")) are both special methods that return **strings based on the state of the object**.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name,breed,owner):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.owner = owner
    
    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.__class__) + '\n'+ '\n'.join(('{} = {}'.format(item, self.__dict__[item]) for item in self.__dict__))

    
class Person():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
    
    def __str__(self):
        return  str(self.__class__) + '\n'+ '\n'.join(('{} = {}'.format(item, self.__dict__[item]) for item in self.__dict__))

mick = Person("Mick Jagger")
dog = Dog("Stanley","French Bulldog", mick)
print(dog.owner)
```

****str****

> If you print an object, or pass it to format, str.format, or str, then
> if a **str** method is defined, that method will be called, otherwise,
> **repr** will be used.

****repr****

> The **repr** method is called by the builtin function repr and is what
> is echoed on your python shell when it evaluates an expression that
> returns an object.

Comment: nice good one : )

Answer (score 1):

when you assign `self.owner = owner` self.owner stores the reference of owner object you should access the name value by mentioning the attribute `self.owner = owner.name`.

```
class Dog():
    def __init__(self,name,breed,owner):
        self.name = name
        self.breed = breed
        self.owner_name = owner.name

class Person():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name


mick = Person("Mick Jagger")
dog = Dog("Stanley","French Bulldog",mick)
print(dog.owner_name)
```

Comment: Thank you! This was really simplified and easy to understand!!

Comment: @Elix I appreciate this is a simple version but I was curious what if `Person` class has another attribute in future e.g age, then are you going to access each individually or by just `self.owner = owner` and then `dog.owner.name` or `dog.owner.age`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I tried creating an age attribute but it's only printing the owner's name, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: have another instance variable for dog like ```self.owner_age``` and assign it to ```owner.age``` like ```self.owner_age=owner.age``` or simply store owner object as ```self.owner = owner``` and refer ```dog.owner.age``` to make it simple ```dog.owner``` returns the orginal owner object and ```.age``` returns his age. remember self refers to the current instance

Comment: @Elix that's why I think the old code is good because you don't need to create multiple separate assignments. By the way best of luck with "Easy to understand" version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `__repr__` and `__str__` methods to the Person class. Or just `__repr__`.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name=name
    def __repr__(self)
        return str(self.name)
```